# Help me Prove the logarithmic inequality

Tags: inequality

I need prove the follow inequality: $$\log_2 3+\log_3 2>2.$$

My attemp is:
$$\log_2 3+\log_3 2=\frac{\log3}{\log2}+\frac{\log2}{\log3}>2$$

But I didnt now how to continue. Please  help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For positive $x$, the function $f(x)=x+\dfrac1x$ achieves a single minimum at $x=1$ such that $f(1)=2$.

---

For a more precise estimate,

$$2048=2^{11}<3^7=2187\text{ and }3^5=243<256=2^8$$ hence

$$\frac{11}7<\frac{\log(3)}{\log(2)}<\frac85$$

and

$$\frac{\log(3)}{\log(2)}+\frac{\log(2)}{\log(3)}>\frac{11}7+\frac58=\frac{123}{56}\approx 2.1964$$

The true value is $\approx2.2159$. You can improve on this result by any tighter rational bracketing of $\frac{\log(3)}{\log(2)}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to prove that $a+{1\over a}>2$ where $a={log3 \over log2}$. This is easily proved as follows
$$
\eqalign{
& a+{1\over a} > 2 \cr
\leftrightarrow & a^2+2a{1\over a}+{1\over a^2} > 4 \cr
\leftrightarrow & a^2+2+{1\over a^2} > 4 \cr
\leftrightarrow & a^2-2+{1\over a^2} > 0 \cr
\leftrightarrow & \biggl( a-{1\over a} \biggr)^2 > 0 \cr
}
$$